# Что означает 14-я строка?

Tags: reactjs

[image]
Помогите разобрать что означает 14-я строка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentlyEditing` будет иметь значение `true`, или `false` в зависимости от того `editIdx` строго равен `i` (не только по значению, но и по типу), или нет

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `currentlyEditing` будет иметь в себе значение 
    `true` или `false` в зависимости будет ли `editIdx` равен значению `і`.

Если равен тогда `true`, если нет тогда `false`.